# How to connect oracle 11g db and sql power architect?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have made a ER diagram of a database in sql power arch. I wanted to create the whole table- schemas in oracle db, so 1st I have to connect [oracle11g](/questions/tagged/oracle11g) db and sql power architect.

The error line is, `- jdbc DRIVER " oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver " not found`

Answer (score 5):

SQL Power Architect doesn`t have Oracle JDBC drivers out-of-the-box. You should download it manually and load into the SQL Architect.

You should follow the next steps:

1. Choose the version of Oracle DB (11g in your case),
2. Download the appropriate JDBC driver from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to the desired location on your PC (for example, I use jdbc folder inside architect folder),
3. Open SQL Power Architect,
4. In SQL Power Architect go to File->User Preferences, then choose 'JDBC Drivers' tab,
5. Choose the desired database type and version from the tree on the left,
6. Press button 'Add JAR...' on the right and choose the downloaded on step 3 JDBC Driver file,
7. That`s all. Go to Connections and create new connection using choosen database.

Sources: SQL Power Architect [FAQ](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/faq-install).

Answer (score 0):

Download [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) for your version of DB, install it and register it inside your client application (usually somewhere in connection preferences or settings).